# Basic math question bugging me.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

My friend showed me this picture: 
[image]

I did the math and I got 27.65 however my friend states it's 35, is one of us wrong? What would the correct answer be?

The way I received 27.65 as the answer is:

Purple hair (P): 2 * **15** = 30

White Shirt (W): (**3.16228**^2) + (**3.16228**^2) = 20

Black Shirt (B): 2 * **4** = 8

P + (W * B) = 15 + (3.16228*4) = 27.65

Sidenote, this is my first post here and I'm sorry if this was tagged in the wrong section, in this forum it says it's open to all levels, so if I tagged incorrectly will a moderator please move it to the correct location. Thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with order theory?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern I wanted to tag order of operations, there wasn't any sort of tag found. I'm sorry, do you know where this sort of question would fit so I can tag it and remove this from order theory?

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the second line (the young woman with the white shirt). My first intuition was that it was
$$2x + 2x = 20 \quad\implies\quad x = 5,$$
and not multiplied as you seem to have interpreted it as. However, obviously this is not really a super well-defined rigorous math problem. My interpretation leads to
$$15+5\times 4 = 15 + 20 = 35.$$

Comment: @Eff The reason I thought it was the way of exponents is that It's a copy of the same person (or the same value). So the answer can go either way, or would I have the wrong answer more or less?

Comment: @user7014825 Well, that's the problem with these sort of social media "math problems." They are usually poorly defined and often just set up to confuse you. In mathematics we usually try to precisely define everything to minimize any confusion. 
But in my personal opinion, it seems more likely that the "correct" answer is 35. I don't really see how a copy leads to exponents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the second line.  I would agree with your friend that there are four girls on the left, so each counts $5$.  Your reading that having two in a single frame means they should be multiplied seems somewhat strange, particularly as it leads to an irrational number.  These problems are usually restricted to integers.  There is no truly right answer unless one defines it as whatever the problem setter had in mind and I don't think your reading is crazy.  If you are going to read it that way I wouldn't round off, I would report the result as $15+4\sqrt{10}$, which I think is another indication that it is not the intended answer.

Comment: I didn't know that integers wouldn't be used in an exponent case. I always thought that if I see a number next to another of the same number (3.16228)(3.16228) it could be also be written as (3.16228^2). I guess I just don't know much about this huh, haha.

Comment: It's the reason I used exponent's in the first place, I saw a value which is right next to the same value, without an operator sign, so I assumed they were within closed brackets, and were meant to be multiplied.

Comment: @user7014825 I think the second equation is meant to illustrate the following:
$$2\text{ girls } + 2\text{ girls } = 20.$$
And then we can simplify the left hand side
$$2\text{ girls } + 2\text{ girls } = 4 \text{ girls}.$$

Comment: @Eff Yeah I see that more clearly now, but I still feel stupid for thinking the way I did, I just thought that it wouldn't be a pair of girls rather copies. Thank you.

Comment: @user7014825:  I certainly don't think you should feel stupid.  Questions like this often have more than one reasonable answer.  Generally we consider the "simplest" answer to be correct, but sometimes that is in the eye of the beholder.